# An integral with respect to the Haar measure on a unitary group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $A,D\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be diagonal matrices. I need to calculate 
$$\int_{U(n)}\det{(A-HDH^\dagger)}\,\mathrm{d}H$$ 
where $dH$ is the unit invariant Haar measure on the group of unitary matrices and $H^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $H$. (If $A=I$ this is very easy to solve, but I want the answer for $A\neq I$ in terms of $A$ and $D$.)

Comment: First of all, the matrices should probably be in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ not in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Second, what role does $D$ play? I don't see it in the integral, perhaps $D = L$? Third, what does $H'$ mean? Is it the transpose of $H$? Fourth, are the words "deterministic" really relevant here?

Comment: Oops, Sorry for these typos! I edited them. Does it make sense now? Thanks.

Comment: Wlog one can assume that $A$ is diagonal because the Haar measure is invariant under left- and rightmultiplication.

Comment: Do you need an exact answer or would large $n$ asymptotics suffice? In the second situation, in the case where $A$ and $D$ are diagonal with free entries, one might be able to use an approximation of the spectral distribution of $A-HDH^*$ ($H$ chosen uniformly at random) by the free convolution of $\mu_A$ with $\mu_D$, see e.g. the first few pages of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809193

Comment: Thanks, this is going to help for large $n$. But I need the exact answer.

Comment: there is no hope for an exact answer in closed form; if $D$ is small or $A$ is large, you can evaluate a few terms in the power series, of the form $\int {\rm tr}\,(A^{-1}HDH^\dagger)^p\,dH$, which can be done in closed form for small $p$ (but not for any $p$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my Problem $A>D$, and the first few terms in the expansion may give a good approximate. I still do not know how to evaluate $\int \exp (\sum_{p}tr(A^{-1}HDH^{\dagger})^p) dH$. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @Peter: Just a follow up on Carlo's suggestion. I don't think you want to compute the integral of exp sum of traces as in your last comment. $\int\exp(t\ {\rm tr}(A^{-1}HDH^{\dagger}))dH$ is enough, then take derivatives in $t$. That's the famous Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral. See e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : Thank you. The problem is that using the formula for Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral, we can come up with $\int (\mathrm{tr}(A^{-1}HDH^{\dagger}))^p dH$. But we need the answer for   $\int \mathrm{tr}((A^{-1}HDH^{\dagger})^p) dH$. In addition, the formula for Harish-Chandra-Itzykson-Zuber integral is valid for nonzero $t$, while I need to take $p$ consecutive derivatives and set $t=0$. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

Let $A={\rm diag}[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ and $B={\rm diag}[b_1,\dots,b_n]$. Let $\Delta(a)$ be the Vandermonde product in the $a_j$, and similarly $\Delta(b)$ be the Vandermonde product in the $b_k$. Suppose ${\rm min} \, a_j \ge {\rm max} \, b_k$. Let ${\rm d}U$ denote the normalised Haar measure on the unitary group $U(n)$. Then by Eq. (3.21) in Gross and Richards, "Total positivity, spherical series, and hypergeometric functions of matrix argument", J. Approx. Th. vol. 59 (1989): 224-246,
$$
\int_U \det(A - U B U^\dagger)^p {\rm d}U = c_{n,p} {\det [ (a_j - b_k)^{p+n-1}]_{j,k=1}^n \over \Delta(a) \Delta(b)},
$$
where $c_{n,p} = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{p+n-1}{j}^{-1}$. Setting $p=1$, subject to the condition ${\rm min} \, a_j \ge {\rm max} \, b_k$, this is the sought evaluation. See Theorem 2.3 in Kieburg, Kuijlaars and Stivigny, "Singular value statistics of matrix products with truncated unitary matrices", IMRN vol. 2016 (2016) 3392-3424 for a generalisation.